# Font appearance in Chrome on Windows

Tags: html, css, windows, google-chrome, fonts

I have a website (http://oxfordmint.co.uk/) which uses the avenir font, on my mac this font renders fine however on Windows Chrome small shapes appear around some the text specifically my h3 tag.

[Font on Windows:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U43EO.png)

---

**Edit:** The font is hosted on Wordpress using a plugin which I now suspect maybe the issue, I will change how I host the fonts and see if that helps
Thanks everyone!

---

Does anyone know what has caused this or what the fix is? 
thanks in advance!

Comment: Just tested on Chrome 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) and the text displays correctly with the avenir font. I would test on multiple versions of browsers and platforms using browser stack or other similar solutions. (fellow rider here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its about the Chrome i try another windows browser and they are fine. Chrome cannot set character encoding properly. You may want to look at that.